# Does .NET Framework 4.6 remove the need of all previous .NET Framework versions?

Tags: .net-framework

Does .NET Framework 4.6 remove the need of all previous .NET Framework versions?

I mean, once you install .NET Framework 4.6, it covers all previous versions of .NET Framework and you don't need any previous .NET Framework version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Does .NET Framework 4.6 remove the need of all previous .NET versions?

It depends on how the applications using .NET are built.

> Some changes in the .NET Framework may require changes to your app code; see [Application Compatibility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn458358(v=vs.110).aspx) before you run your existing apps with the .NET Framework 4.5 or later versions.

and

> In addition, if your app targets version 2.0, 3.0, or 3.5, your users may be required to enable the .NET Framework 3.5 on a Windows 8 or Windows 8.1 computer before they can run your app. For more information, see [Installing the .NET Framework 3.5 on Windows 8 and later versions](http://installing%20the%20.net%20framework%203.5%20on%20windows%208%20and%20later%20versions/).

Source [.NET Framework Versions and Dependencies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb822049%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Thanks David for enlightening us with your knowledge. Regards.